# Sorting by multiple attributes

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

my task is

1) By the quantity of solved tasks in descending order

2) When the quantities of solved tasks are equal – by the penalty time in ascending order

3) When both quantities of solved tasks and penalty times are equal – by the indices of teams in ascending order.

input file gonna be like this:

The first line contains a natural number n (1 ≤ n≤105) – the quantity of teams participating in the contest.

The next n lines contain two numbers S – the quantity of solved tasks (0 ≤ S ≤ 100) and the penalty time T (1 ≤ T ≤ 1000000) of the ith team.

Example:

> 6
>
> 3 50
>
> 5 720
>
> 1 7
>
> 0 0
>
> 8 500
>
> 8 500

so output file will be:

> 5 6 2 1 3 4

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void printArray(int A[],int B[], int size)
{
    int i,xx;
    for (i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            if (A[i] == B[x]) {
                cout << x+1 << " ";
                //break;
            }
        }

    }


}
int main()
{

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int qarray, largest;

    cin >> qarray;
    int *task = new int[qarray];
    int *newtask = new int[qarray];
    int *time = new int[qarray];
    for (int i = 0; i < qarray; i++)
    {
        cin >> task[i];
        cin >> time[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= qarray - 1; i++) {
        newtask[i] = task[i];
    }

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < qarray - 1; i++) {

    // Last i elements are already in place    
        for (j = 0; j < qarray - i - 1; j++) {
            if (task[j] > task[j + 1]) {
            swap(&task[j], &task[j + 1]);
        }
        }

}

    printArray(task, newtask,qarray);


    return 0;

}
```

In short I'm tottaly stucked

Comment: I suggest you to create a `class` that stores `S` and `T`.

Comment: I would use a vector of structs that contain the S and T values. Fill it with your input an then use std::sort with a custom comparator provided by a lambda.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use vectors and lambda or any special library I have to do without library

Answer (score 0):

Standard library solution (you can replace std::sort with your own sort function):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


struct Team
{
   std::uint32_t number;
   std::uint32_t quantity;
   std::uint32_t penalty;

   bool operator < (const Team& other) const
   {
       bool isEqQuantity = quantity == other.quantity;
       bool isEqPenalty  = penalty == other.penalty;

       return quantity > other.quantity 
           || (isEqQuantity && penalty < other.penalty)
           || (isEqQuantity && isEqPenalty && number < other.number);
   }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Team> teams;

    //Read teams from file
    //....

    //Or use other sort
    std::sort(teams.begin(), teams.end(), [](const Team& t1, const Team& t2)
    {
        return t1 < t2;
    });

    for (auto& t : teams)
    {
        std::cout << t.number << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but like I said in comment I have to do it without using vectors and sorting algorithm